# Fortran/C/Cpp Exe being detectes as virus

Tags: c, fortran

My question is very basic. Every time i compile my fortran (or even c/cpp) code, the .exe file is detected as a virus. (I have mcAfee anti-virus). I have tried added the .exe to the exclusion list of mcAfee realtime scanning, but the anti-virus removes it from the exclusion list and then deletes the .exe. I have also tried to turn off the real-time scan.The exe runs but then i get a warning which is very irritating. Although i can bear with getting a warning, i dont want to turn off my anti-virus. So is there any other way i can run my code without getting an error.

Comment: One possible way: Run on online compiler or inside a virtual machine without compiling locally (Oops, I said "One" but I wrote actually two...)

Comment: It sounds like you want McAfee's support resources.  I'm not sure there's much we can do for you.

Comment: ok. is there at least a way in which i can exclude a whole folder in the real time scan?

Comment: @TheParallax This site is for questions about programming. Your question is merely about configuring your antivirus program, so might get closed as being off-topic. Did you read the corresponding documentation? Does this problem occur with every program you compile or does it depend on the code? Please [edit] your question to answer.

Comment: All my programs are detected as viruses.

Comment: Many antivirus programs consider a program that writes executables (linker, etc.) to be indicative of malware. Most programs let you exclude a specific folder from real-time virus checking. If yours does, tell it about your development folder. I'll note that Windows Defender never complains about my Fortran EXEs.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  I've experienced this once with VS2019 but it went away after changing the compilation model.  When I changed it back, the warning just disappeared.

Comment: I am using gcc and g++ for c and cpp. For fortran I am using gfortran. I built my gcc and g++ from Cygwin and and downloaded gfortran from mingw

Comment: Did you try to name your executables with another file name extension? If that works, upload it to (for example) VirusTotal to check it. There is a very small possibility that your system is compromised and actually generates malware-laden executables. -- If your system is clean, you will need McAfee's support, and we cannot help you.